# How to add a shared mail box to homepage of Outlook on the web

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, shared-mailbox

In the Outlook local app I have access to a shared mailbox. It shows up beneath my personal mailbox on the left column. However when I go to Outlook on the web it is not there. I tried following [these directions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-and-use-a-shared-mailbox-in-outlook-web-app-bc127866-42be-4de7-92ae-1ef2f787fd5c) but there is no option to add a shared folder. From [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pa_AcO7NWkE) I learned it could be accessed by clicking on the profile picture and selecting "open another mailbox". Is there a way to have it linked to the home page of Outlook on the web so it's easy to check?

Answer (score 0):

This will add a tile to the App Launcher (9 dots top left) whilst in office 365 and I think it requires admin permsissions to initially setup. However I am unable to find a way to add a tile to the actual homepage of office 365 as such.

Firstly use the "open another mailbox" method you already know, once in the mailbox copy the URL which should be similar to `https://outlook.office.com/mail/<PrimarySMTPofMailbox>`.

Then follow these instructions obtained from [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/customize-the-app-launcher?view=o365-worldwide) - When you get to step 5 you will need to use the URL that you have copied when you were in the mailbox previously.

**Add a custom tile to the app launcher**

1. In the admin center, go to the **Settings** > **Org Settings** and choose
   **Organization profile** tab.
2. On the **Organization profile** tab, choose **Custom app launcher tiles**.
3. Select **Add a custom tile**.
4. Enter a **Tile name** for the new tile. The name will appear in the
   tile.
5. Enter a **URL of website** for the tile. This is the location where you
   want your users to go when they select the tile on the app launcher.
   Use HTTPS in the URL. TIP: If you're creating a tile for a
   SharePoint site, navigate to that site, copy the URL, and paste it
   here. The URL of your default team site looks like this:
   https://<company_name>.sharepoint.com
6. Enter an **URL of the image** for the tile. The image appears on the My
   apps page and app launcher. TIP: The image should be 60x60 pixels
   and be available to everyone in your organization without requiring
   authentication.
7. Enter a **Description** for the tile. You see this when you select the
   tile on the My apps page and select App details.
8. Select Save changes to create the custom tile.

Your custom tile now appears in the app launcher on the All tab for you and your users.

**Promote the tile to App Launcher**

Select the app launcher icon and select the **All apps**.

Locate the new tile for your app, select the ellipsis, and choose **Pin to launcher**.

Please note that after making these changes that it may take a while for the changes to transtion. Also it would be a good idea to clear your browser cache after a few minutes to ensure that your browser has not cached the app launcher menu.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the steps mentioned in this official article to Open and use a shared mailbox in Outlook on the web.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/open-and-use-a-shared-mailbox-in-outlook-on-the-web-98b5a90d-4e38-415d-a030-f09a4cd28207?ui=en-us&rs=en-gb&ad=gb